# Does QtNetworkAuth support PKCE

Tags: c++, qt, oauth-2.0, qt5, pkce

I use Qt5. I did not find any documentation on how to enable PKCE when using QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow.

If so, please provide the link. If there is no support, how can this feature be added to it?

I added `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method`, but it is not enough. I don't know what the next step is.

```
#include <QtNetworkAuth/QtNetworkAuth>

void loginHelper()
{
   auto* authFlow = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow;
   QObject::connect(authFlow, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);
   authFlow->setScope("openid profile email mobile");
   authFlow->setAuthorizationUrl(QUrl("https://accounts.XYZ.com/core/connect/authorize")); // url is changed
   authFlow->setClientIdentifier("desktop.test");
   authFlow->setAccessTokenUrl(QUrl("https://accounts.XYZ.com/core/connect/token")); // url is changed
   authFlow->setClientIdentifierSharedKey("0323af0d-efe2-fcec-b450-72f102530a77");
   authFlow->setModifyParametersFunction([=](QAbstractOAuth::Stage, QVariantMap* params)
      {
         params->insert("code_challenge", "1Kht0Wkyt_WvDngoM_AIOYPPOWG8lzVG1g1zk28TjSo");
         params->insert("code_challenge_method", "S256");
      });
   auto* replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(1234); // port number
   authFlow->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
   QObject::connect(authFlow, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, []()
      {
         qDebug() << "Access Granted!";
      });
   authFlow->grant();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step is to set `code_verifier` at `RequestingAccessToken` stage.

```
auto code_verifier = (QUuid::createUuid().toString(QUuid::WithoutBraces) +
   QUuid::createUuid().toString(QUuid::WithoutBraces)).toLatin1(); // 43 <= length <= 128
auto code_challenge = QCryptographicHash::hash(code_verifier, QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toBase64(
   QByteArray::Base64UrlEncoding | QByteArray::OmitTrailingEquals);
authFlow.setModifyParametersFunction([=](QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QVariantMap* params)
{
   switch (stage)
   {
   case QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAuthorization:
      params->insert("code_challenge", code_challenge);
      params->insert("code_challenge_method", "S256");
      break;
   case QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAccessToken:
      params->insert("code_verifier", code_verifier);
      break;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Yes, and you are using it.

Reading [the new flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-3) you notice there are three new parameters used by PKCE, `code_verifier`, `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method`.

These are used in your code, so you are using PKCE already.

Comment: I expected `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow` to support it internally and I did not need to add `code_challenge` and so on.
However, adding `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method` is not enough and I will not receive the `granted` signal. In fact, the first step is done, but in the next step, `code_verifier` is needed and must be checked to receive an access token. How should this be done?